# Angular gamesparks issue

Tags: angular, service

I am trying to make my GameSparks SDK a service inside Angular but am having some issues.

Here is my service.ts script:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// Import GameSparks SDK //
import * as gs from '../../assets/gamesparks/gamesparks.js';
import * as gsf from '../../assets/gamesparks/gamesparks-functions.js';
import * as cryptojs from '../../assets/gamesparks/hmac-sha256.js';


const gsKey = 'XXXXXXXX';
const gsSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
// var gsCredentials = "";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GamesparksService {

  isLive = false;

  gamesparks = new gs.GameSparks();

  init() {

    if (this.isLive) {
        this.gamesparks.initLive({
            key: gsKey,
            secret: gsSecret,
            // credential: gsCredentials,
            onNonce: this.onNonce,
            onInit: this.onInit,
            onMessage: this.onMessage,
            logger: console.log,
        });
    } else {
        this.gamesparks.initPreview({
            key: gsKey,
            secret: gsSecret,
            // credential: gsCredentials,
            onNonce: this.onNonce,
            onInit: this.onInit,
            onMessage: this.onMessage,
            logger: console.log,
        });
    }

  }

  // Callback function to hmac sha256 a nonce with the secret. It's assumed you will have your own method of securing the secret;
  onNonce(nonce) {
    return cryptojs.CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(cryptojs.CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(nonce, gsSecret));
  }

  // Callback to handle when the SDK is initialised and ready to go
  onInit() {
    console.log('Initialised');
  }

  // Callback to handle async messages from the gamesparks platform
  onMessage(message) {
    // console.log('onMessage: ' + JSON.stringify(message['scriptData']));
  }

}
```

When trying to run init() at the beginning I get this error in my console, referring to this: gamesparks = new gs.GameSparks();

**AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: _assets_gamesparks_gamesparks_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.GameSparks is not a constructor
    at new GamesparksService (gamesparks.service.ts:21)**

What am I missing here?!?
Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Remove `new` operator in line `gamesparks = new gs.GameSparks()`. You calling a functions that should return `new` object.

Comment: @Mises - This brings up this error: AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: _assets_gamesparks_gamesparks_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.GameSparks is not a function
    at new GamesparksService (gamesparks.service.ts:21). Any idea?

Comment: Oh so remove `()` if it is not a fuction.

Comment: Well, I think it is... This is how it is initiated in the gamesparks sdk: var GameSparks = function() {}; If I remove the () I get this error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'initPreview' of undefined

Comment: So think what You can do You have problem at line 21.